# How to express idiomatically in this situation: please slide in the middle of the slide or stay away from the edge?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

Look at this picture

[image]

The kid seems to slide on the edge of the slide, which is dangerous as she may fall off. I want her to slide in the middle of the slide.

What should I say "**please slide in the middle of the slide or stay away from the edge**"?

But, do we have a common expression that can be used in other situations?

For example, a kid may sit on the edge of a table or a chair, which is dangerous.

Or, someone walks on the edge of a bank which may fall into the river.

DO we say, "**please do/go in the middle of... & stay away from the edge**"? or **Do we have an idiomatic way to express them?**

Comment: The slide appears to me to be curved with high sides, so the little girl can't help but sit in the middle; you can see that her legs are almost hidden behind the edge nearest the camera. However, "Stay away from the edge" would suit most of the situations you describe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When speaking to children, generally idiomatic expressions relating to safety are the exception rather than the norm. I would likely choose something direct:

> Make sure you **stay in the middle**!

or

> Stay away from the sides!

Though, you could of course say something indirect though not necessarily idiomatic:

> Watch you **don't fall**!

If you *really* wanted an idiom, you could use something like:

> Careful you don't **go flying**!

At least in the UK, to "go flying" is often used to mean falling over, tripping up, falling off something, etc. in an unexpected manner. However, I don't think I'd use this unless the child already knew *how* they might "go flying."